# Numerical Analysis: Computer Arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

I need to add, multiply fractions

(i) Exactly using three-digit decimal arithmetic with chopping

(ii) With three-digit arithmetic with rounding

Say we had

$$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{10}$$

$$\frac{1}{6}=0.16666666$$

Chopping it to three-digit decimal we have $0.166$.

Rounding it to three-digit decimal we have $0.167$.

Question:

As $\frac{1}{10}$ is exactly $0.1$, there is nothing to chop or round. So I just add the two? For example, $$0.166 + 0.1 = 0.266$$, $$0.167 + 0.1 = 0.267$$

This is the correct answer is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct answer. Rounding and chopping only apply when the number you are adding has a representation that is greater than your storage capacity.

Comment: Multiplying is not any different as long as I perform the necessary chopping and rounding as demonstrated above.

Comment: Yup, I believe that is correct